# google-cloud-cpp CMake Generation Failed

Tags: c++, google-cloud-platform, cmake, cmake-gui, google-cloud-cpp

I'm trying to build google-cloud-cpp, but I get an error (see below). I have attempted building it using both VC++ and `g++`, but I get the same error during with both. I use cmake-gui.

- Build Environment : Visual Studios 2017
  OS : Windows 10 Pro 64-bit
- Build Environment : Mingw-w64 8.1.0
  OS : Windows 10 Pro 64-bit

Target : 64-bit

Error:

```
CMake Error at cmake/IncludeGMock.cmake:38 (add_library):
  Cannot find source file:

    D:/google-cloud-cpp/third_party/googletest/googletest/src/gtest-all.cc

  Tried extensions .c .C .c++ .cc .cpp .cxx .cu .m .M .mm .h .hh .h++ .hm
  .hpp .hxx .in .txx
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/GoogleCloudCppCommon.cmake:48 (include)
  google/cloud/CMakeLists.txt:42 (include)


CMake Error at cmake/IncludeGMock.cmake:38 (add_library):
  No SOURCES given to target: gmock
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/GoogleCloudCppCommon.cmake:48 (include)
  google/cloud/CMakeLists.txt:42 (include)
```

Comment: difficult to comment unless you can supply exact steps to reproduce. Have you filed a ticket with google?

Comment: Is your [third_party/](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-cpp/tree/master/third_party) subdirectory empty? If so, then you forgot to clone google-cloud-cpp project **with submodules**.

Comment: It looks like as if your `third_party` directory is empty. Those subprojects are part of the project as git submodules, which means you either need to do `git checkout --recursive` or a `git submodule update --init` if the project is already checked out.

Comment: I built libcurl.dll as required by google-cloud-cpp. I ran configure (via configure button) which completed successfully. When I clicked generate button I get the error.

Answer (score 0):

After git clone https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-cpp.git

Enter directory

Run git submodule update --init